# How to assert the opposite value from that of the matching?

Tags: regex, rules, clips, expert-system

I have a rule that has a slot that does a matching with two colours, and it doesn't matter which one it will match as long as after the matching it changes to its opposite colour. However when I write this, I get a syntax error:

```
(defrule colour
?col <- (colorTemp(color ?color&white|black))
=>
(modify ?col (color ?colorOpposite&~?color))
)
```

Thank you

Comment: What error do you get? Please include it in the question. 
What do you mean by "opposite color"? How do you define a color being the opposite of another one?

Comment: Thank you for answering, I get a syntax error in the modify part, so if for example it matches with black then I want to modify it to white and vice versa

Comment: Please copy-paste the entire error message in the question. See the [how to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) SO reference. How does the system knows black is opposite of white? Do you have it defined somewhere as a rule?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The syntax ?colorOpposite&~?color is not valid in the actions of a rule and the variable ?colorOpposite is not bound anywhere in the rule so both of these issues will generate errors. You also need to add some code that specifies the color opposites. To prevent looping from one opposite to the other, you will need to indicate some way that the color has been changed.

```
         CLIPS (6.31 6/12/19)
CLIPS> 
(deftemplate colorTemp
   (slot color)
   (slot changed (default no)))
CLIPS>    
(deffacts opposites
   (opposite white black))
CLIPS> 
(defrule colour
   ?col <- (colorTemp (color ?color&white|black)
                      (changed no))
   (or (opposite ?color ?opposite)
       (opposite ?opposite ?color))
   =>
   (modify ?col (color ?opposite)
                (changed yes)))
CLIPS> (reset)
CLIPS> (assert (colorTemp (color white)))
<Fact-2>
CLIPS> (facts)
f-0     (initial-fact)
f-1     (opposite white black)
f-2     (colorTemp (color white) (changed no))
For a total of 3 facts.
CLIPS> (agenda)
0      colour: f-2,f-1
For a total of 1 activation.
CLIPS> (run)
CLIPS> (facts)
f-0     (initial-fact)
f-1     (opposite white black)
f-3     (colorTemp (color black) (changed yes))
For a total of 3 facts.
CLIPS>
```